# Removing trivial background using GrabCut

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to remove relatively trivial background from several images where the background tends to be white. However, the mask generated overlaps the foreground even when it doesn't contain much white. For instance, given the following input:

[image]

GrabCut gives:

[image]

And here's my code:

```py
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

height, width, _ = img.shape

rect = (int(width * 0.05), 0, height, int(width * 0.9))

cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

I'm actually trying to imitate Photoshop's Magic Wand, which would easily pick out the white background. Anyone know of a good way using opencv? Is there a way to tweak GrabCut to do similar?

UPDATE: After fixing the rectangle, I'm now getting a mask that leaves a gap:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rect = (int(width * 0.05), 0, height, int(width * 0.9))
```

look closely. you have something proportional to width in 1st and 4th position. that's probably wrong. [the elements are (x,y,w,h)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html).

additionally, you base your observation on matplotlib's false color drawing. maybe have it draw true colors.

Comment: Thanks. I got H and W mixed up indeed. I've now fixed the rect and the result is much better. However, the mask leaves a large gap even when there're 5 iterations. Please see update.